# Publish a specific TeamCity artifact to NuGet

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have set up a local NuGet gallery and want to publish my build artifacts to it. Rather than publishing every single build artifact to the Nuget gallery each time there is a build, I want to be able to publish a specific version of the artifact manually when I am satisfied that it is a stable version.

Is there a way to do that in TeamCity?

Comment: Are you using the built in NuGet feed in TeamCity?

Comment: No, we have a NuGet gallery setup. We are not usin the TC NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly simple option is to create a build chain, with a Package build having a snapshot dependency on the CI build:

`CI Build -> Package Build`

That way you can manually trigger the Package build once you're ready.  You'll need to move your Pack / Publish build steps in to the Package build of course.

You can target specific change-sets as well if you're not looking to publish the 'latest' build.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have accepted your answer, but what I ended up doing is slightly different (although I am not sure if that's wht you meant).

I created a build dependency on the step which generated the packages. Then In the publish task (which has a dependency on package task), I can click on the run custom build and select the specific build I want to publish!!